# Is it ok to drive a stepper motor below it's rated current?

Tags: current, driver, stepper-motor

I got two of these:

```
Frame size 42 x 42mm - NEMA 17
1.8 degree step angle
Length 47mm
Holding torque 44 N.cm (4.4kg.cm, 62oz.in)
Voltage 2.8V
Current/Phase 1.68A
Resistance/Phase 1.65ohm
Inductance/Phase 2.8mH
Inertia 68g.cm
Bipolar, 4-wire
```

I'm using a micro controller board. I've been looking on different ways to drive the motors. For example this one: [Big Easy Driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11876).
But most driver boards I looked at has a limit of around 1.4A before they get overheated. Is it ok to drive these motors at 1.4A? Or should I find any other Driver/board/chip/controller?

I'm open to any suggestions of driver/setup to drive these motors via usb communication...

Thanks :)

Comment: Connecting a 1.68A motor to a 1.4A driver will try to draw 1.68A from the driver. The driver will overheat. You could add some series resistance to reduce the current, but that would make the motors weaker and may not work properly. There are plenty of higher power drivers out there - don't look for toy (i.e., Arduino) ones since they are designed for toy motors. Look for proper ones, maybe with external FETs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for making that clear. I need to control it via usb though. You got any suggestions?

Comment: This is a arduino usage question, not about electronics.  We are not the arduino help desk.

Comment: It's not only about arduino, it's also about current and stepper motors.

Comment: @Majenko A chopper drive such as the Big Easy Driver is more like a dual current source where the maximum phase currents are determined by the current-adjust, not the current rating of the motor. It is perfectly acceptable to run a 1.68A motor at a reduced current so long as there is enough torque for the application. The reduced current will allow both motor and drive to run cooler.

Comment: But your first sentence mentions "arduino", at which point it seemed pointless to read the rest of the question.  If this really is a electronics question, then you can ask it without mentioning arduino.  About the only valid arduino questions here are those where you don't have to mention the arduino is envolved.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I agree... My first thought was to just ask the current question. But then somehow I changed my mind, probably because i thought people would ask "What are you using your stepper with" etc... In my question i wrote "suggestions" so basicly i am open to other electronic setups... Like bigger Microstepping drivers.

Comment: @tut thank you! I see the word Arduino is making people react... I'll be nice and remove the word, and this might not be "off-topic".

Comment: I'm not sure why this is off-topic while http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/143731/25328 is not. I think they both should be on topic. They are both about stepper motors. At least this one is also about stepper drives which is closer to electronics design.

Comment: @galengodis While I don't feel that your question is off topic, I do think your title is too broad. Might I suggest something like "Is it ok to drive a stepper motor below it's rated current?"

Comment: @tut ok I change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same motors for an Arduino Uno project. For maximum torque I used [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TB6560-Single-axis-Stepper-Controller-Electronics/dp/B00D781T16) (TB6560 3A Single-axis Stepper Motor Driver Controller Board).
You can buy it on ebay cheaper.

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to set the max current per motor somewhere on the board? So I don't give too much current...