# Accelerating a stepper motor without it making noise

Tags: arduino, signal, stepper-motor, timer, c++

I am having some issues moving my stepper motors without it making noise.

I read somewhere that ramping the frequency of the pulse modulated signal would help, but seems to have same issues as well.  Is the "acceleration" to steep..?

The stepper motor i am using is a [PK244-01A](http://fablabo.net/mediawiki/images/ORIENTAL_MOTOR_GENERAL_CATALOGUE.pdf), and it is connected to a driver board, which has requires the input signal enable, direction and step => which is the one i am ramping. [Driverboard](http://www.sainsmart.com/zen/documents/20-019-201/ST330%20%20Stepper%20Motor%20Driver%20Board%20User%20Manual.pdf)

HEre is the code:

```
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //Step
      pinMode(12,OUTPUT); //en
      pinMode(13,OUTPUT); //dir
      TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) ; // phase and frequency correct mode. NON-inverted mode
      TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS11);     // Select mode 8
                                           // Prescaled by 8 on main clock.
    }


    float count = 1000; //

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      //output_freq = CPU_clk/(2*8*ICR1_value)
      //ICR1 = CPU_clk/2*8*output_freq
      digitalWrite(12,HIGH);

      delay(1);

      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);

      delay(1);
      ICR1 = count;
      OCR1A = int(count/2);

      while(1)
      {
         if(count != 20)
         {
           count -= 10;
         }
      }
    }


The ICR1 value is computes using this formula $$ICR1 = \frac{(cpu_{freq})}{(2*prescaler*desired_{freq}))}$$
```

**Updated the code with @jms answers:**

```
void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(230400);
      pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //Step
      pinMode(12,OUTPUT); //en
      pinMode(13,OUTPUT); //dir
      TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1) ; // phase and frequency correct mode. NON-inverted mode
      TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS11);     // Select mode 8
                                           // Prescaled by 8 on main clock.
    }


    int count = 200000;

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      //output_freq = CPU_clk/(2*8*ICR1_value)
      //ICR1 = CPU_clk/2*8*output_freq
      digitalWrite(12,HIGH);

      delay(1);

      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);

      delay(1);


      while(1)
      {


        int freq = (16000000)/(2*8*ICR1);

        ICR1 = count;
        OCR1A = int(count/2);

        Serial.print("freq: ");
        Serial.println(freq);
        Serial.print('\n');
        Serial.print("count: ");
        Serial.println(count);
        Serial.print('\n');
      }
```

Comment: What sort of noise is it making? I would expect a stepper to 'hum', as  the typical step rate is well within human hearing, a few dozen Hz to a few kHz.

Comment: humming is correct.

Comment: So what causes you to think it can be made inaudible? Are you hoping to push the frequency above human hearing range? Also  please post a link to the motor and controller datasheets.

Comment: Well..? you make it sound like it is not possible?
But yes.. pushing above human hearing would be one way..

Comment: Like. MRI's and paper scanners alike which use high commutation rate current pulses, they will buzz (e.g. 400 hz with harmonics) but not HUM like 50/60Hz. Speeds may be ramped to avoid slip.  Are you using their PS or your own? I would suspect the supply contributes the HUM. You can reduce the buzz slightly with viscous rotary oil filled brass-disc dampers or micro-stepping with a loss of torque. then use a belt drive.

Comment: Smoother operation without so much hum and outight noise is to move to servo motor instead of stepper.

Comment: I am microstepping already.  
I am using my own power supply, but there should not be any problem with what i can deliver

Comment: did you scope the supply for ripple? is it magnetostiction noise or bearing or winding noise?

Comment: It sound like bearing or winding noise.. quite sure..

Comment: Are the cables isolated and shielded? with ferrite CM chokes

Comment: ...No, does my code work work correctly?

Comment: I would suspect a bit noise like this 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYIL5gxRogM

But mine make a lot more noise.  The max freq. i reach is 48 khz.

Comment: that's normal noise like a scanner.  bracket stiffness can amplify resonance if not done right. with sub harmonics of cycles

Comment: ST-506 HDD's in the early 80's used very quiet stepper drivers and ramped speed to get faster

Comment: So count = 1000 the first time through loop, and count is supposed to be 20 the second time through loop. Is that what you intended? If not, reconsider that while(1), because you'll never leave it.

Comment: This is only done for testing purposes.. 
count decided the frequency the signal should have, and is being decremented within the while loop. 
count = 48 khz => which was my desired speed.   eventhough it doesn't look like the speed is changing that much.

Comment: could this be explained?
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143731/why-do-we-need-a-ramp-for-stepper-motor

Comment: http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4006438/Generate-stepper-motor-speed-profiles-in-real-time

Comment: Q1. Is the motor turning through complete rotations, smoothly, or is it just 'vibrating'? Q2. Is the motor drive configured for 16-step microstepping on its DIP switches?

Comment: It does complete rotations.. Smoothly... well it moves and the vibrating can be heard clearly.. 

The motor driver is configured for 16 microstepping yes .

Comment: When you say 'the vibrating can be heard clearly' can you estimate how loud you mean? Is it louder than the average laptop PC fan when it's not doing anything, louder than a mosquito or house fly, louder than a laptop PC fan when its playing full-screen video, louder than an electric toothbrush (not in your mouth)? The datasheet isn't very clear, when it is configured for 16-microstepping, do you feed it one pulse, and it does 16 microsteps, or do you need to feed it one pulse for each microstep, ie. feed it pulses at 16x full-step rate?

Comment: "Louder than electric toothbrush" If that is quantitive a definition. 
Yes the datasheet doesn't say that much ...

Comment: The program doesn't do any acceleration ramping. It tries to *instantly* start at 16,000,000MHz/8/1000 = 2kpulses/second step rate. If the driver does 16 microsteps/input step, then it should be driving at 32kHz. Getting up to speed may be noisy, it will be passing through its resonance range. However, once it is up to speed, the noise should reduce. Does it? Also is the motor connected to a load, how big is it. Is the motor or load mechanically coupled (i.e. bolted, screwed, glued, etc) to something which is amplifying the noise or resonating?

Comment: There the motor has a belt which drives a small convyerbelt

Comment: Hmm, electric toothbrush is quite loud. I agree it isn't very quantitative, so if you can thing of something better, that would be good. My NEMA 1.7 steppers (very different models from yours, recovered from printers), are quieter than an electric toothbrush even when driven with 1/2 steps without load, sitting on a rubber mouse mat.

Comment: I guess I could try with the code posted above..  I read somewhere that changing the decay mode might aswell affect the noise.

Comment: Just for comparison, can you disconnect your motor and sit it on something compliant, like a rubber mouse mat, just for comparison with them in their normal conveyor belt mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

- Your current code doesn't do any ramping at all. After configuring timer 1 to output a square wave at the "step" output, your code just enters an infinite loop with no exit condition (`while(1){...`).

  ```
  void loop() {
      ...
      ICR1 = count;
      OCR1A = int(count/2);

      while(1)
      {
          if(count != 20)
          {
              count -= 10;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Yes, the `count` variable does get decremented by 10 every time the while loop runs one iteration, *but the timer registers which control the waveform aren't actually updated*. ICR1 and OCR1A aren't pointers to data to be read, if that is what you thought.
- You don't have any delay in the step period decrement loop, so you wouldn't get a controlled speed ramp even if you did update the timer registers in said loop.
- You really want to avoid using floating point arithmetic on a 8-bit microcontroller (which lacks a floating point unit). Not only can many floating point operations take milliseconds to compute, but your compiler has to include hefty floating point library functions which drastically blow up your code size. In this case floats don't even have any advantage, as you are only calculating with integers.
- Testing floats (as in `if(count != 20)...`) for equality (or inequality) is generally a bad idea on any platform. Floating point numbers are not perfect real numbers, and suffer from e.g. limited precision and rounding errors. You might think that 10.000002 and 10.000000 are the same, but your computer will disagree.

  ```
  float a = 0.0, b = 10.0;
  for(int n = 100; n > 0; --n)
      a = a + 0.1;

  if(a != b)
      printf("a and b are not equal!\n");
  printf("a: %f, b: %f", a, b);  

  //prints out:  
  //a and b are not equal!
  //a: 10.000002, b: 10.000000
  ```

Comment: Your suggestion regarding

Comment: 1)
Yes you are right, that there is no exit, which was intended. This was made for testing purposes. I do see i miss updating the ICR1A and OCR1A within while, but again. Easily fixable

Comment: 2) The delay, how would you suggest making it when the timer runs "in the background"? delay(1) would not change the pin as far i understand?

Comment: 3) Yes... You are definetly on point with that Will change them to int.

Comment: 4) thats the same.. And i did notice that the change didn't do that much..  But other than that? what you are suggesting isn't any major change? so it should basically work?